# Regex for a certain number of digits

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to select rows from postgres where a part number has a three digit number (300-399) near the beginning. I just need a match/no match.

I'm mostly there with:

`WHERE name ~ '^[A-Z]{0,5}3[0-9]{2}[^0-9]?*'`

The part numbers

1. can be just 3 digits long,
2. can have up to 5 characters before the number
3. can have characters after the number
4. must exclude 4 digit numbers

These should match:

- 323
- A335
- AB359-B2
- BB311BB

These should not match:

- 3234
- A3357
- AB3590-B

With the above, the 'should match' pass, but the 'should not match' are also passing. It seems the question mark that checks for a non-digit ([^0-9]?) allows the digits through, but I can't make it required since a simple 3-digit part number would not match.

Thanks!

Comment: `?` makes your non-digit optional. So yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regexp passes all your tests.

```
 '^[^\d]{0,5}\d{1,3}(\y|[^\d])'
```

The first caret `^` anchors to the start.

The `[^\d]{0,5}` allows up to five non-digit characters.

The `\d{1,3}` allows one to three each digit characters.

The `(\y|[^\d])` alternation matches either a non-digit character or a word boundary such as the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you tried could possibly also match the first 3 digits in a string with 4 digits as the character class at the end is optional `[^0-9]?`

If you don't make it optional `[^0-9]`, it would not match a only `323` as there is a character expected after it which is any char except a digit.

---

If there can be characters after the number, but not a digit, you can use a negative lookahead `(?!\d)` to assert not a digit directly to the right.

```
^[A-Z]{0,5}3[0-9]{2}(?!\d)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]{0,5}` Match 0-5 times a char A-Z
- `3[0-9]{2}` Match `3` and 2 digits
- `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not a digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U32RkY/1) | [Postgresql demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jNbxVbHugBREn8c7wMWJEW/0)